# why when I console.log(event) for `from` onSubmit, I don't see that preventDefault method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React.js.  In the code below I use a form and I am trying to see what that `even` contains. So I `console.log` it. But then I noticed in the log I don't have that `preventDefault` method. So, where is that coming from? why when I log the even it's not there?

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('cons');
        this.onInputchange = this.onInputchange.bind(this);

        this.state = { name: 'Dear. ' };
    }

    onInputchange(event) {     
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    onFormSubmit (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        debugger;  
    }

    render() {
        console.log('rende');
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group" borderColor='pink'>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.onInputchange}
                    placeholder="enter the name please "
                />
                <span className="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">submit</button>
                </span>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It says `defaultPrevented: true`.

Comment: Scroll down. Inspect the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi   thanks, please post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows in the *proto*. Please find the screenshot below for the same.

[image]